# Elevators to space

Tags: gravity

Gravity and vacuum got me thinking... we fight gravity and friction to reach escape velocity. Given that we are really only talking a few miles is it feasible to transport using a vacuum shielded for particles. When matter is introduced this may create gravity, but can you shield against that? Therefore a vacuum tube that reached to space would allow matter to be transported. The larger the vacuum the larger the matter being able to be transported. How wrong am I?

Comment: read this interesting [competitor site](http://www.askamathematician.com/2014/11/q-what-would-happen-if-there-was-a-giant-straw-connecting-the-earths-atmosphere-right-above-the-ground-to-space/)

Comment: More on [space elevators](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+space+elevator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't shield against gravity. If you could, you could just shield gravity from one side of a wheel and make a perpetual motion machine. [Space elevators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) have been considered, but you still have to fight against gravity and friction. It just means that you can just climb a rope instead of using a rocket.

Comment: Can I clarify the gravitational force is the same on the earth surface even if you were contained inside a vacuum. I presume because you are the mass inside the vacuum.

Comment: Being in a vacuum does not affect gravity. I do not know what you mean about being the mass inside the vacuum.

Comment: Gravity is an attractive force that affects and is effected by all mass. In a vacuum there is no mass so why would it be affected by gravity. If you place a mass inside the vacuum such as a mouse is it then affected by gravity as much as a mouse outside the vacuum

Comment: @middleearthman - Yes, a box with a mouse, and perfect vacuum weighs MORE than a box without a mouse.  (Though, a perfect vacuum can't technically be created, because there is a mouse, or rather a dead mouse, in it.)

Comment: @middleearthman Gravity comes from massive objects, but the gravitational field it crates doesn't need to be carried by massive objects. It's not like sound, where it needs a medium. It can travel through a vacuum just fine, like light.